# Sunspot search by id

Tags: solr, sunspot

Is there any way to search entity by id with subspot

like so:

```
Content.search do
  with(:ids, [1,2,3])
end
```

Comment: I just add id like regular field. but there should be ability to search on system fields. Maybe need dig into solr documentation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to achieve this is indexing the `id` field:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :id
    # ...
  end
end
```